# codeigniter, error Message: Creating default object from empty value

Tags: codeigniter, stdclass

severity: Warning
Message: Creating default object from empty value
Filename: controllers/person.php
line Number: 133

```
   function update($id)
        {
            $responce = new StdClass;
            $this->_set_rules();
            $person = $this->Person_model->get_by_id($id)->row();

error in this line i  try to figure it ot
           $this->form_data->id = $id; 


            $this->form_data->name = $person->name;
            $this->form_data->gender = strtoupper($person->gender);
            $this->form_data->dob = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($person->dob));


            $data['title'] = 'Update person';
            $data['message'] = '';
            $data['action'] = site_url('person/updatePerson');
            $data['link_back'] = anchor('person/index/','Back to list of persons',array('class'=>'back'));

            // load view
            $this->load->view('personEdit', $data);
        }
```

Comment: Creating default object from empty value

Comment: If you like my answer please consider to "up-vote"

Comment: Where is form_data coming from? I see you are obtaining data from Person_model and saving the result row to variable $person...but I don't see where you are declaring form_data (at least within this function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lowercase "s" in stdClass:

```
$response = new stdClass;
```

NOT:

```
$responce = new StdClass;
```

Find out more on PHP objects here:
http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.object.php

Comment: Just a heads up. Response is spelled with a 's', not a 'c' (regardless if you are from the UK or USA).
So the best answer would be `$response = new StdClass;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the data object as shown below.

```
$responce = new stdClass();
```

Hope this will solve your error.